# Better representation of a barh in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a`Counter()` element that I want to represent as some kind of graph.

Each element is a string-value pair, and the string could be long, so I opted for legibility to use a `barh` graph. How can I write all this better? Can I do something like a vertical dashed line that is automatically positioned at the end of each bar? How can I add the legend to both axis? I achieved to only change the colour. Suggestions to better represent the graph are very well accepted.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.barh(list(count_single_obf.keys()), list(count_single_obf.values()), color = "lightgreen")
```

`count_single_obf` printed returns this:

```
Counter({'EncodeArithmetic': 49,
         'EncodeLiterals': 98,
         'Flatten': 71,
         'InitEntropy': 29,
         'InitImplicitFlow': 3,
         'InitOpaque': 100,
         'RandomFuns': 82,
         'Split': 99,
         'base': 7})
```

Moreover, before printing the graph, it prints this line: `<BarContainer object of 9 artists>`; why? How to avoid it? I'm using Jupyter notebook.

[image]

Comment: To avoid that the result of the last statement in a notebook is printed out, add a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the line. This tricks creates an empty statement, which has no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted based on your data. I think when you mean legend you rather meant the x and y labels. I have chosen to represent the bar vertical so that a horizontal line can be drawn. The horizontal line here shows the mean values of the category as a threshold.

Below is the code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
example_dict = {'EncodeArithmetic': 49,
         'EncodeLiterals': 98,
         'Flatten': 71,
         'InitEntropy': 29,
         'InitImplicitFlow': 3,
         'InitOpaque': 100,
         'RandomFuns': 82,
         'Split': 99,
         'base': 7}


plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.bar(list(example_dict.keys()), list(example_dict.values()), color="lightgreen")
plt.axhline(np.asarray(list(example_dict.values())).mean(), color="gray") # Horizontal line adding the threshold
plt.xlabel("Category") # x label
plt.ylabel("Frequency") # y label
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Output]